# Ошибка SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, pygame

```
while True:
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_SPACE or event.key == K_UP):
            return
        else:
            display_screen_window.blit(game_image['background'], (0, 0))
            display_screen_window.blit(game_image['player'], (p_x, p_y))
            display_screen_window.blit(game_image['message'], (msgx, msgy))
            display_screen_window.blit(game_image['base'], (b_x, play_ground))
```

Comment: Естественно. У вас же функции нет, зачем нужен `return`?

Comment: Изучение python стоит начать с азов, а потом уже переходить к сложным библиотекам, вроде `pygame`.

Comment: @Глеб, наоборот, "азы" в отрыве от каких-то более-менее практических задач проблематично изучать (даже если это не первый язык). Начинать сразу с pygame вполне нормально, только сам язык тоже параллельно изучать.

Comment: @insolor, вообще да, но конкретно pygame — непростая библиотека. Там же все повязано на ООП, и человеку, который даже плохо представляет себе, что такое функция, будет очень трудно.